# java JSP coding in learning management system

Tags: java, jsp

I am working on a project named as LMS (Learning management system) and the modules allocated to me are:-

1. The uploaded course content saved as ppt,doc ,pdf or audio/video file should be opened in the same window.The application by which file needs to be opened should be embedded in the context window itself.
2. The uploaded course content saved as ppt,doc ,pdf file can be converted to audio/video file.

I have to code them in JSP.

Being new to java i am not getting how to do these. Can you plz plz help me out by showing me some direction? I shall be very thankful to you.

I will be waiting for your reply desperately.

Thanks and regards
swati

Answer (score 0):

First I have to ask do you already have a transformation server/code to do the conversion in point nbr2 or do you ask for guidance on that to? If that's the case maybe you can look into HTML5 for this otherwise use something like flash.

I would say use HTML5 for video and the other things I would require the users to install the correct plug in adobe reader ... I think it's reasonable to put requirements on the user when using an enterprise app.

Almost all of this could be done in HTML JavaScript inside your jsp.